# saxon transform xml with url parameters

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I got an xhtml file containing links with multiple parameters :

```
index.jsp?foo=bar&foo2=bar2&foo3=bar3.
```

Saxon 9.5 tries to interpret &foo2 as an entity and obviously fails.
I cannot change my xml (it is a web page from internet), I could pre-process it with some regex but want to avoid programming if possible.

```
java -jar %SAXON_HOME%\saxon9he.jar -xsl:transfo.xsl -s:pageWeb.xml -o:result.html -dtd:off --recognize-uri-query-parameters:false
```

does not work.
Is it possible without modifying the xml ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you feed something to an XML parser that is not well-formed XML then the parser is going to reject it, that is why there is a specification. And Saxon simply relies on an XML parser to process its input documents and stylesheets.

If you have input that is not well-formed then you can try to use a different parser like [TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) or the [HTML5 parser](http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/), you need to tell Saxon to use it using the `-x` option e.g. `java -jar %SAXON_HOME%\saxon9he.jar -x:org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser ...` or `java -jar %SAXON_HOME%\saxon9he.jar -x:nu.validator.htmlparser.sax.HtmlParser ...`.